# What command is used to start Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-2d, remote-desktop, freenx

Trying to use FreeNX remote desktop which requires a custom command for the window manager. I tried unity-2d-launcher but that just starts the launcher missing the panel for instance (which can be started with unity-2d-panel). How do I start the whole thing?

Comment: Found it out myself:

`gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d`

Comment: If you add this as answer and accept it, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu 11.10, please use "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d".

For "NX Client for Windows"

1. Press "Configure..." button
2. At "Desktop", select "Unix" and "Custom", press "Settings..."
3. Choose "Run the following command", fill in "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d"

Comment: You also need to set the "New virtual desktop" option