# Using NX with Unity in 11.10

Tags: unity, 11.10, nx

I'm trying to use nx to login remotely to my desktop. But when I do, because of unity I get the following screen:

[image: My NX Client]

It looks like all I can do is access the file browser from here. I tried following the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50503/why-do-i-get-unity-instead-of-classic-when-using-nx), but they don't work (presumably because I don't have the necessary gnome stuff). How do I launch the unity-2d "session" on 11.10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d` as the command in your NX client.

Comment: As I said in my question above, doing this does not work.

Comment: You know, I'm not the kind of guy who guesses without saying so. Before I wrote that answer, I tested it myself. Perhaps you should consider updating your answer to provide more details?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I tried it again and it's working now. I'd reversed the phrases and had typed in 2d-ubuntu instead of ubuntu-2d

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: I wasn't sure where in the NX client to enter this command.  See the following answer for more details: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69522/what-command-is-used-to-start-unity-2d

Answer (score 2):

The problem is described on [this nomachine webpage](http://www.nomachine.com/ar/view.php?ar_id=AR0500591).

I had to check which sessions are available for gnome-session in `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions` and modify the session startup (`--session=gnome-classic` changed to `--session=gnome`).