# GTK unthemed and ugly over NX

Tags: 11.10, gtk, nx

I just installed nx-server on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 11.10.
I've also followed the instructions as in [Using NX with Unity in 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71233/using-nx-with-unity-in-11-10) to specify the session I want to be loaded.

It works all right, and I can play with unity-2d or with gnome-classic by just changing the setting of the nx-client.

There is just one glitch remaining, that is that, regardless of the session launched or the theme chosen in system settings, the gtk controls are un-themed, and are just plain ugly. It's like when gnome-settings-daemon is not running if you know what I mean (yes I checked it was running). The picture posted in the question before mentioned (although showing a different problem) explains it all.

Any possible fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Nomachine NX in quite a few years, but I can confirm that X2go works, if you're willing to give another NX-solution a try. X2go is quite nice, with PulseAudio support and everything.

I do remember a similar issue a few years ago with FreeNX. Back then, if I remember correctly, it had something to do with libxklavier, if you want a starting point.